# Difference between try{..}catch{...} with finally and without it

Tags: c#, try-catch, try-catch-finally

What is the difference between code like this:

```
string path = @"c:\users\public\test.txt";
System.IO.StreamReader file = new System.IO.StreamReader(path);
char[] buffer = new char[10];
try
{
    file.ReadBlock(buffer, index, buffer.Length);
}
catch (System.IO.IOException e)
{
    Console.WriteLine("Error reading from {0}. Message = {1}", path, e.Message);
}

finally
{
    if (file != null)
    {
        file.Close();
    }
}
```

and this:

```
string path = @"c:\users\public\test.txt";
System.IO.StreamReader file = new System.IO.StreamReader(path);
char[] buffer = new char[10];
try
{
    file.ReadBlock(buffer, index, buffer.Length);
}
catch (System.IO.IOException e)
{
    Console.WriteLine("Error reading from {0}. Message = {1}", path, e.Message);
}
if (file != null)
{
    file.Close();
}
```

Is really finally block necessary in this construction. Why Microsoft provided such construction? It seems to be redundant. Isn't it?

Comment: The finally block is guaranteed to run, whatever messed up in the rest of the try construction. Say Console.WriteLine raised an exception - the Close would not be run.

Comment: Rather than try to manage an instance of `StreamReader` yourself, why not wrap it in a `using` block?

Comment: 'using' block should be used to avoid questions like this one. This code should not have been written your way since it is overcomplicated.

Comment: @48klocs @Ilya Palkin This code is taken from c# Reference (http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/vstudio/dszsf989.aspx). My purpose was to understand the construction. I agree that `using` block would be the better solution in this situation.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Imagine if some other exception occurred that you haven't handled, e.g. an `ArgumentOutOfRangeException`, or if you want to rethrow the exception or throw a wrapped exception from your catch block:

1. The first block would ensure that the file is closed regardless of whether or not an exception occurred.
2. The second block would **only** close the file if either no exception occurred or an `IOException` occurred. It does not handle any other cases.

N.B. The first block also ensures the file is closed if an exception is thrown from *inside* the catch block itself.

Answer (score 7):

The first block will close the file even if there is an uncaught exception.

The second block will close the file only if there are no exceptions, or any thrown exceptions are caught.

The first will also ensure that the file is closed if the `try` has a `break`, `goto`, `return`, `continue`, or any other jump construct that would cause the execution to move outside of the `try` block.  The second doesn't, and as such it could result in the resource not being closed.

Comment: +1 for mentioning the jumps. Personally, I tend to avoid having any such constructs within a try block, but that's good point.

Comment: @p.s.w.g It's not uncommon at all for a `try/finally` or `using` to cover the whole scope of a method.  It often makes sense to have a `return` at the end to return the value.  In most cases this will even be at the end of the try/using block, where the reader would expect it to be, but the expression for what is returned may use the disposable resource, so extracting it to after the end of the block really adds more complexity than it saves.

Comment: That's true, I frequently have returns inside usings, but I can usually avoid it inside a try/catch. Nothing really wrong with it, just personal preference I suppose. (although goto is bad enough to warrant it's own criticism regardless of what's around it)

Answer (score 2):

In your example, if your code throws an exception other than `System.IO.IOException`, your cleanup code is not guaranteed to run. With the `finally` block, the code within it will run no matter what type of exception is thrown.

Comment: If i'd use `catch(Exception e)`  in both examples they could be considered as equal?

Answer (score 1):

Imagine there was an exception inside `catch{}`, code inside finally would still run but `if (file != null){}` block will not.

Answer (score 1):

In that case it's redundant.

It's usefull if you for example will rethrow an exception and still want some code to run after the block:

```
try {
  // do something dangerous
} catch(...) {
  // log the error or something
  throw; // let the exception bubble up to the caller
} finally {
  // this always runs
}
// this only runs if there was no exception
```

Another example is if the catch may throw an exception for a different reason:

```
try {
  // do something dangerous
} catch(...) {
  // handle the error
  // log the error, which may cause a different exception
} finally {
  // this runs even if the catch crashed
}
// this only runs if there was no exception, or the code in the catch worked
```

Simply, as code might crash for plenty of reasons you might not even know about, it's useful to put the cleanup in a `finally` block just to be sure that it runs whatever happens.

Comment: What is more, if you use `return`, `break`, `goto`, `continue` in `catch` block, finally block executes anyway.

Comment: @Matjanos it executes on a `goto` even?

Comment: @ScottChamberlain: Yes, if you step out of the `try` or `catch` block with a `goto`, the `finally` block still executes. I wasn't sure about this, but I tested it, and it does.

Comment: I wonder, what about the reverse, what about stepping into a `try` block with a `goto`? Does the call stack get set up on steping over the `try` or would entering mid method still execute the `finally` (and the `catch` for that matter)

Comment: @ScottChamberlain: You can't do that. A label inside a `try` structure is not within the scope of a `goto` that is outside it.

Comment: Why the downvote? If you don't explain what it is that you think is wrong, it can't improve the answer.

Comment: This should be the accepted answer, since it's the only one that actually answers both the question that is asked, and also presents the reasoning behind the finally block. All other answers have the word "if" in the first sentence which isn't what was asked.